# Is it possible to load a pdf document via ajax and display it in the Browser?

Tags: ajax, pdf, binary, pdf-generation

I found a short tutorial on creating a pdf webservice, which I tried out and it works like a charm.

Now just to test this I wrote a little jquery one-liner, that accesses that webservice, the return value of the service is:

```
{ success: true, pdf: A_BUNCH_OF_BASE64_ENCODED_DATA }
```

Now I would like to display the Binary Data as a PDF in the browser.

Unfortunately storing the file on the server and then requesting the file is not an option, since this is a webservice and it is supposed to return json.

Is something like that even possible?

Comment: so you are looking for a way to convert the base64 data into a file/url?

Answer (score 0):

have you try the pdf.js library; 
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js